# Remove every second word separated by whitespace from a line using perl?

Tags: perl, substitution

I'd like to remove the second word in string. What is the best way?
Can I use "substitution" for this? Thanks a lot for your answer!

```
hostname1: test.20330.9861.runscript: warning: this option is disabled in the BIOS;
```

Desired output:

```
hostname1: warning: this option is disabled in the BIOS;
```

Comment: Please, look at @terdon's answer and adapt your question if applicable. Otherwise your question will be very confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will work to remove the 2nd word `s/\S\K\s+\S+//;`.

Note how it handles the case where there is leading space before the first word:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    # Remove 2nd Word
    s/\S\K\s+\S+//;
    print;
}

__DATA__
hostname1: test.20330.9861.runscript: warning: this option is disabled in the BIOS;
 hostname1: test.20330.9861.runscript: warning: this option is disabled in the BIOS;
```

Outputs:

```
hostname1: warning: this option is disabled in the BIOS;
 hostname1: warning: this option is disabled in the BIOS;
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove second word in string,

```
$line =~ s/ \S+//;
```

Comment: That will take `\W` as a word separator, not whitespace. In the OP's example, it also deletes `20330`.

Comment: Thank you! mpapec. Your query is working fine:) ScayTrase Thank you for the advise.

Answer (score 1):

Your output shows that you don't want to remove every second word but just *the* second word. In that case, use one of

```
$ perl -lane '@F[1]=""; print "@F"' file
hostname1:  warning: this option is disabled in the BIOS;
```

or, if part of a larger script:

```
$line=~s/( \S+)//;
```

Alternatively, if this is being run on a file, it might be simpler to use `awk` instead:

```
$ awk '{$2="";}1' file
hostname1:  warning: this option is disabled in the BIOS;
```

Comment: +1 for "ignoring" the question and sticking to the desired output.